# Selecting certain values from an XML document depending on other values

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML

```xml
<OrderReport>
  <Item>
    <Promotion>      
      <Component>
        <Type>Principal</Type>
        <Amount currency="USD">-0.25</Amount>
      </Component>
      <Component>
        <Type>Shipping</Type>
        <Amount currency="USD">0.00</Amount>
      </Component>
    </Promotion>
  </Item>
</OrderReport>
```

I need to get the Amounts for each type. Below is what I'm trying

```
var q = from orders in xDoc.Descendants("OrderReport")    
        select new 
        {
            //This should return me the Principal Amount
            ItemDiscountAmount = orders.Element("Item")
                                       .Element("Promotion")
                                       .Element("Component")
                                       .Element("Amount")
                                       .Value,
            //This should return me the Principal Currency
            ItemDiscountCurrency = orders.Element("Item")
                                         .Element("Promotion")
                                         .Element("Component")
                                         .Element("Amount")
                                         .Attribute("currency")
                                         .Value,

            //This should return me the Shipping Amount
            ShipDiscountAmount = orders.Element("Item")
                                       .Element("Promotion")
                                       .Element("Component")
                                       .Element("Amount")
                                       .Value,
            //This should return me the Shipping Currency                        
            ShipDiscountCurrency = orders.Element("Item")
                                         .Element("Promotion")
                                         .Element("Component")
                                         .Element("Amount")
                                         .Attribute("currency")
                                         .Value,
        };
```

The code I have written is incorrect. It returns me Principal Amount and Currency for all the properties right now. The comments describe what should be returned in it for understanding purpose.
The query should basically return me the Prices and Currency depending on the `<Type>` node under `<Component>` node. Not sure how to put a condition in this case.

Comment: I think your class structure leaves room for improvement. Make a class `Amount` with `Value` and `Currency` properties. Make a class `Item` with `Tax`, `ShipTax`, etc. properties.

Comment: You're going to have to rephrase your question.  I have no idea what you're asking for and I suspect others will feel the same way.  (and your code would not even compile)

Comment: @Sjoerd - I get the XML from third party application which I can only use in my application.
@Jeff Mercado - Sorry about that. Let me see how can I make it better.

Comment: @sjoerd - Can you check it now. I have edited the question
@jeff-mercado - Can you check it now. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you first find the elements that contained the `Principal` type or `Shipping` type first, then get the desired values.  I believe this is what you're after.

```
// using an XPATH will make this nicer to express
var query = from report in xDoc.Descendants("OrderReport")
            let principalAmount = report.XPathSelectElement("./*/*/Component[Type='Principal']/Amount")
            let shippingAmount = report.XPathSelectElement("./*/*/Component[Type='Shipping']/Amount")
            select new
            {
                ItemDiscountAmount = (decimal)principalAmount,
                ItemDiscountCurrency = (string)principalAmount.Attribute("currency"),
                ShipDiscountAmount = (decimal)shippingAmount,
                ShipDiscountCurrency = (string)shippingAmount.Attribute("currency"),
            };
```

Just remember to include the namespace `System.Xml.XPath` for this to work.

Comment: That was great. Worked like a charm :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add Where clause,

```
var q = from orders in xdoc1.Descendants("OrderReport")
        join ItemPrices in xdoc1.Descendants 
        where orders.Component.Type == "Principal"
        select new 
        {
            OrderId = orders.Element("OrderID"),
            City = orders.Element("City"),
            CountryRegion = orders.Element("CountryCode"),
            State = orders.Element("StateOrRegion"),
            Street1 = orders.Element("AddressFieldOne"),
            Telephone = orders.Element("PhoneNumber"),
            ZipCode = orders.Element("PostalCode"),
            Name = orders.Element("Name"),
            OrderDate = orders.Element("OrderDate"),
            ShipMethod = orders.Element("FulfillmentMethod"),
            ItemCode = orders.Element("AmazonOrderItemCode"),
            SKU = orders.Element("SKU"),
            QtyOrdered = orders.Element(""),
            ItemTaxAmount = orders.Element(""),
            ItemTaxCurrency = orders.Element(""),
            ItemShipTaxAmount = orders.Element(""),
            ItemShipTaxCurrency = orders.Element(""),
            ItemTotalAmount = orders.Element(""),
            ItemTotalCurrency = orders.Element(""),
            ItemUnitPrice = orders.Element(""),
            ItemCommissionAmount = orders.Element(""),
            ItemCommissionCurrency = orders.Element("")
         };
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander,
But using where clause I will only get the Principal amount. Is there no way I can get all the amounts in the single select? If you see I have got properties for Principal, Tax, Ship all amounts in my select.

Comment: you might extend you where clause with AND operator.. Principal && Tax && Ship

Comment: Can you check it now. I have edited the question to make it more specific to the problem area.